# Where should I store variable which is used in common in the same controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Now I'm doing just like this. Is this supposed to be normal?
Or is there something else to do this in the other way, which is more popular way?

**users_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :set_variable

def set_variable
    @number_of_records_to_display = 10  
    @number_of_tags_to_display = 10 
end

def index
...
        @users = User.find_by_username(params[:id]).all_following(order: 'updated_at DESC')
        @users = Kaminari.paginate_array(@users).page(params[:page]).per(@number_of_records_to_display)
        @tags = User.tag_counts_on(:tags, :limit => @number_of_tags_to_display, :order => "id desc")
...
end
```

Comment: before_filter is correct method to do it a controller, or define them in initializers and use them as constants.

Comment: Thanks! how do you do it? could you show me an example in Asnwer please??

Comment: No @ is required for instance variable, what Sachin suggested is appropriate or you just have one intialiser file and put all your constants there would be easy to manage

Answer (score 2):

what you are doing is correct and appropriate, since you may use only for some actions not all so you can use only clause with the before_filter

before_filter your_method, only: [:show, :index]

but also you can use initializers, or define constants in your environment files. Let me know if you need the code or more help.

If using an intializer, you may define your Constants in a file say constants.rb and place it in config/initializers folder,in that file just have
PAGE_SIZE = 10
TAG_COUNT = 10,

this constants would be available everywhere in your app once you start the app.

Comment: Yes I want to know how to do that in initializer

Answer (score 2):

No need to define method, you can define as controller's constant

```
NUMBER_OF_RECORD_DISPLAY = 10
NUMBER_OF_TAGS_DISPLAY = 10

def index
...
        @users = User.find_by_username(params[:id]).all_following(order: 'updated_at DESC')
        @users = Kaminari.paginate_array(@users).page(params[:page]).per(NUMBER_OF_RECORD_DISPLAY)
        @tags = User.tag_counts_on(:tags, :limit => NUMBER_OF_TAGS_DISPLAY, :order => "id desc")
...
end
```

Comment: I tried your way but it says this error `undefined local variable or method `number_of_tags_to_display' for #<UsersController:0x00000009dab278>`

Comment: UsersController::NUMBER_OF_RECORD_DISPLAY use like this. Sorry for late reply.